# Memory error during large dynamic array allocation (malloc) in C. It works fine with smaller arrays

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc, dynamic-arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
        int** arr;
        int size_row,size_col,i,j;
        arr = (int**) malloc(size_row*(sizeof(int*)));
        printf("enter the size of the row\n");
        scanf("%d",&size_row);
        printf("enter the size of the column\n");
        scanf("%d",&size_col);
        for(i=0;i<size_row;i++)
        {
                *(arr+i) = (int*) malloc(size_col*(sizeof(int)));
        }
        for(i=0;i<size_row;i++)
        {
                for(j=0;j<size_col;j++)
                {
                        printf("arr[%d][%d]=  ",i,j);
                        scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
                }
        }
        for(i=0;i<size_row;i++)
        {
                for(j=0;j<size_col;j++)
                {
                        printf("arr[%d][%d][%p]=%d\n",i,j,&arr[i][j],arr[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
        }
}
```

*This code works fine for smaller arrays. However, if I put row size = 9 and column size = 1000 it shows Segmentation fault (core dumped). But if I put row size = 1000 and column size = 9, it works fine. Why is this memory error? I am using gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0 compiler. Thanks in advance.*

Comment: `arr = (int**) malloc(size_row*(sizeof(int*)));` you have not initialized `size_row` when this statement is executed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

size_row not initialized before use.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a little more info on that?

Comment: printf("enter the size of the row\n");
scanf("%d",&size_row);
arr = (int**) malloc(size_row*(sizeof(int*)));